# Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem's original proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles, fibration

I'm trying to understand the main ideas used in the original proof
by Lefschetz of his Hyperplane theorem. Here it is sketched shortly
(source: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem#Lefschetz%27s_proof))
and I want to fill the gaps:

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional complex projective algebraic variety closed embedded in
$\mathbb{CP}^n$ and let $Y$ be a hyperplane section of $X$
such that $U = X ∖ Y$ is smooth.

> Lefschetz used his idea of a Lefschetz pencil to prove the theorem.
> Rather than considering the hyperplane section $Y$ alone, he put it into a
> family of hyperplane sections $Y_t$, where $Y = Y_0$. Because a generic
> hyperplane section is smooth, all but a finite number of $Y_t$ are smooth
> varieties. After removing these points from the $t$-plane and making an
> additional finite number of slits, the resulting family of hyperplane sections
> is topologically trivial. That is, it is a product of a generic $Y_t$ with
> an open subset of the $t$-plane. $X$, therefore, can be understood if
> one understands how hyperplane sections are identified across the slits
> and at the singular points. Away from the singular points, the identification
> can be described inductively. At the singular points, the Morse lemma
> implies that there is a choice of coordinate system for $X$ of a particularly
> simple form. This coordinate system can be used to prove the theorem directly.

The original source is 'L'Analysis situs et la géométrie algébrique'
but I can't get along with that text. So I would be happy if someone
could help me to clear up the understanding problems.

That's, what I understand so far: We take any arbitrary pencil $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1}$
of hyperplanes in $X$ with $Y_0=Y$ (that is what we really do is
we take a family $\{H_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1}$ of hyperplanes in
$\mathbb{CP}^n$ such that for every member $H_t$ the intersection $X \cap H_t$
is a $n-1$-dimensional variety with is for almost all $t$ smooth and we
set $Y_t:=  X \cap H_t$.

Then we consider the canonical map $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1} \to \mathbb{CP}^1$,
remove all $t_i$ which have singular fibers (only finitely many) and make some
marvelous cuts $S$ in the projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$ making the the
restriction $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1 ∖ S} \to \mathbb{CP}^1 ∖ S$ trivial.

Although it isn't explicitely explained I think that it is reasonable to assume
that the cuts a done in that way that
$\mathbb{CP}^1 ∖ S$ becomes simply connected, so the fibration becomes trivial.
Is that true? Are the cuts in the original proof indeed done in same spirit like in
the original construction of Riemann surfaces, to make the base simply connected?

So we consider now
$\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1 ∖ S}= Y_0 \times (\mathbb{CP}^1 ∖ S)$. Next the
identifications along the slits are concretely performed. The text refers
to an inductive argument. How is then the induction step done?

Next Morse theory tells us how $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1}$ looks like
in singular points, where we take
$\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1} \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ as Morse function, right?

Well, but finally I not understand how this procedure helps to
reconstruct $X$ (or say better it's homology groups) from these
of $Y$ resp $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{CP}^1}$. What was the advantage in this
construction to work with Lefschetz pencil and why does it contribure a progress in the
computation of the map $H_k(Y) \to H_k(X)$?

Comment: You can check Voisin's book Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, Vol II for details.